# How to calculate the distance between array gameObject?

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, distance, gameobject

How to calculate the distance between the generated cubes. The assigned script on the dice only specifies a different speed. How is the distance between the individual instantiate cubes calculated?
Sorry for the bad English, I'm using google trnslator. I'm attaching the code, and I'm a beginner in the unit

```c#
public class vehicless : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] vehicle;
    [SerializeField] private Transform spawnPos;
    [SerializeField] private float minTime;
    [SerializeField] private float maxTime;

    int randomInt;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnVehicle()); 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {   
    }

    private IEnumerator  SpawnVehicle()
    {
        int i=1;        
        while(true)
        {     
            randomInt = Random.Range(0,vehicle.Length);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(minTime,maxTime));

            GameObject myPrefabInstance = Instantiate(vehicle[randomInt],spawnPos.position,Quaternion.identity);
            var red =   myPrefabInstance.gameObject.name; //NAME OBJECT
             var  namecube  = red + i ;
             Debug.Log("Name object:"+namecube ) ;   
             i++;
         }
    } 
}   


//  float   dist = Vector3.Distance(----------);
```

Thanks for help

Comment: yes, I would like to calculate the distance between the new cubes

Comment: you have an infinite loop..are you sure to do that?

Comment: @Frenchy it is a Coroutine with a `yield` in it so having an endless loop is basically the replacement for an `Update` method ;)

Comment: The distance between what and what? What exactly are you asking for? Or in other words: Without c# or Unity ... what do you refer to by saying you want the distance between multiple objects? ... e.g. The sum of all distances? ... The distance between the last two objects? ... The distance between the last object and a certain reference object?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to quickly find the distance between 2 objects i suggest you to stock the distance in a dictionary with Tuple Key = (GameObject, GameObject) and Value = float:

```c#
 Dictionary<(GameObject, GameObject), float>() 



public Dictionary<(GameObject, GameObject), float>() calculate(GameObject[] objs)
{
    var distanceArray = new Dictionary<(GameObject, GameObject), float>();

    for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < objs.Length; j++)
        {
          if (i == j)
          {
            //distance between same obj is 0f
            continue;
          }
          else
          {
            distanceArray.Add((objs[i], objs[j]), Vector3.Distance(objs[i].transform.position, objs[j].transform.position));
          }
        }
    }
   return distanceArray;
}
```

After you could quickly find the distance between 2 object like this:

```c#
    if (distanceArray.ContainsKey((obj1, obj2)))
    {
        distance = distanceArray[(obj1, obj2)];
    }
    else if (distanceArray.ContainsKey((obj2, obj1)))
    {
        distance = distanceArray[(obj2, obj1)];
    }
    else if (obj1 == obj2)
    {
        distance = 0f;
    }
    else
    {
        //Error
    }
```

Your question is not very easy to understand, i just add the way to calculate the distance after each new spawned vehicle:

```c#
    GameObject myPrefabInstance = Instantiate(vehicle[randomInt],spawnPos.position,Quaternion.identity);
    for (int i = 0; i < vehicle.Length; i++)
    {
        var distance = Vector3.distance(myPrefabInstance.transform.position, vehicle[i].transform.position);
        Debug.Log($"Distance: {distance}");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the cubes have different speeds, objects can be a lot, for example 10.15 cubes and a cube that will have a higher speed to slow down in front of a cube that has a slower speed.

Comment: I would need to find out the current distance between n number of generated cubes
Thanks for help